# What is the Azure ASP.NET Best Practice for WebRoles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

This is my logic - which often is not logical.

I am creating a complex web application on Azure using Cloud Services WebRoles.
I have just come to a cross roads which I would like to get right before doing days of coding to discover I went the wrong path.
I am using a standard WebForm ASP.Net template in VS2013
What is the best practice for the following:

I have a webrole for the public front end. Should we create another webrole for the SuperAdmin website or just add it to the main WebRole?

Thanks for your input.
Dave

Comment: We can't answer this because we don't know what you mean by complex and we don't know the requirements for the public front end and the SuperAdmin site are.

Comment: How can: Should we create another webrole for the SuperAdmin website or just add it to the main WebRole? be regarded as too broad?

Comment: Because we don't know anything about what the requirements/differences are between the two sites. Do you know what the consequences are when you create different webroles or use the same role? That should be you primary consideration. I don't understand how @ragche can give you advice without knowing your requirements and without giving any support for his advice other than I did it and it worked for me.

Comment: So your answer then is - there is no best practice for this. It depends on... not that it is too broad.

Comment: The question is too broad as it currently is lacking detail causing too much speculation and not a single best answer as is the intend of this website.

Comment: I think as usual - some people read more into questions than they need. It is clear what a "public" front end to a website is in general terms, and it is also "clear" what the requirement are for an "Admin" section of a site. You don't need to know what the site does for you to know what these sections of the site are. As for not knowing the meaning of the word "complex" I think Google would have solved that for you.

Comment: As for not knowing the meaning of the word "complex" I think Google would have solved that for you. Also, @ragche answered the question making one reasonable assumption - that is how he answered the question - he didn't try to break everything down into ad absurdum. Too many people on this site are restricting its usefulness because they work to the letter of the rules, and not the "meaning" of them

Comment: " It is clear what a "public" front end to a website is in general terms, and it is also "clear" what the requirement are for an "Admin" section of a site." No it is not clear. Availability and scalability requirements can be very different between sites. 
This is my final remark; comments are not meant for discussion.

Comment: It is clear - Availability and Scalability are taken care of in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a new role.  You can add admin pages to the same role and restrict it to super-admin users.  My answer assumes that your web role will have authentication, in addition to it you would need authorization.  My answer is conceptual/guideline not a specific code answer.  Sorry if you were looking for the latter.

I have hosted many MVC based asp.net applications in azure webrole with varied authorization access and it works like a charm.

Comment: That will do me! Cheers